# An estimate for potential function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f \in C^1\left( {\left[ {0,\infty } \right)} \right)$ be a function verifying

1. $f\left( x \right) = o\left( x \right)$ as $x \to {0^ + }$ and $f\left( x \right) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$;
2. There exists a constant $p>1$ such that the function $u \mapsto \frac{{f\left( u \right)}}{{{u^p}}}$ is strictly increasing in $\left( {0,\infty } \right)$.

My question is: Can we show that there exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$F\left( u \right) \geqslant {C_1}{u^{p + 1}},\,\forall u \in \left[ {0,\infty } \right),$$
where $F\left( u \right) = \int_0^u {f\left( s \right){\text{d}}s} $.

Basically, I proved
$$uf\left( u \right) > \left( {p + 1} \right)F\left( u \right) > 0,\,\forall u \in \left( {0,\infty } \right).$$
As a direct consequence of this fact, we have $F\left( u \right) \gtrsim {u^{p + 1}}$ on $\left[ {{\mathbf{1}},\infty } \right)$. By contrast, we have an inverse inequality $F\left( u \right) \lesssim {u^{p + 1}},\left[ {0,1} \right)$. So, I still do not assert the existence of constant $C$.